# NHibernate - object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm getting the following error:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

I do *not* want to save the transient instance. I'm trying to send validation results back to the client:

```
        if (MyObject.IsValid()) {
            MyObjectRepo.Hydrate(MyObject);
            return Json(MyObject);
        }
        else {                
            Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            test.Add("failure", "failure");
            foreach (var a in MyObject.ValidationResults().ToList()) {
                test.Add(a.PropertyName, a.Message);
            }                
            return Json(test);
```

If the object is not valid and I don't have the test dictionary and foreach statement (for example just sending back, a failure string), it'll work fine. All other questions I've found on this relate to failures saving the object ... the object is not valid and I do not want to save it, just send down the results of the failed validation. Thanks!

Comment: Are you inside an ISession? If so, perhaps do a transaction.RollBack()?

Comment: Ah yes, I have all my methods annotated with [Transaction] ... when I did a manual transaction it worked. Wow, thanks!

Comment: @Goblin Could you change your comment on this two an answer so that it is more useful to people searching?

Answer (score 2):

Are you inside an ISession? If so, perhaps do a transaction.RollBack()?