# NHibernate Error Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using nHibernate and trying to add some master-detail data. The database diagram is attached here.
[image: Database diagram]

The following is the code for adding a category along with two products:

```
//Category
namespace Sample.CustomerService.Domain
{

    public class Category {
        public Category() {
            Products = new List<Product>();
        }
        public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Unit { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            Products.Add(product);
        }
    }
}

//CategoryMap
namespace Sample.CustomerService.Domain
{

    public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category> {

        public CategoryMap() {
            Table("Category");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.CategoryID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("CategoryID");
            Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
            Map(x => x.Unit).Column("Unit").Not.Nullable().Length(3);
            HasMany(x => x.Products).KeyColumn("CategoryID");
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Product
namespace Sample.CustomerService.Domain
{

    public class Product {
        public Product() {
        }
        public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    }
}

//ProductMap
namespace Sample.CustomerService.Domain {


    public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product> {

        public ProductMap() {
            Table("Product");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.ProductID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ProductID");
            References(x => x.Category).Column("CategoryID");
            Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
            Map(x => x.UnitPrice).Column("UnitPrice").Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Program
namespace WindowsHibernateTest
{
    public partial class TestClass : Form
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateNewProduct();
        }

        public void CreateNewProduct()
        {
            try
            {
                var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
                using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                {
                    using (var sqlTrans = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        Category newGold = new Category() { Name = "Gold", Unit = "GRM" };

                        Product ngOrn = new Product() { Name = "Bangles", UnitPrice = 1000.10M };
                        Product ogOrn = new Product() { Name = "Rings", UnitPrice = 2000.10M };

                        AddProductsToCategory(newGold, ngOrn, ogOrn);

                        session.SaveOrUpdate(newGold);

                        sqlTrans.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.
                ConnectionString("Data Source=MyDB; Initial Catalog=NHibernateTest; Trusted_Connection=true;")).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>()).BuildSessionFactory();

        }

        public static void AddProductsToCategory(Category category, params Product[] products)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                category.AddProduct(product);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In the line `sqlTrans.Commit()`, I'm getting the following error:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing. Type: Sample.CustomerService.Domain.Product,
>   Entity: Sample.CustomerService.Domain.Product

I've Googled for quite sometime and didn't get convincing solutions for this. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144402/nhibernate-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transien) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596289/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-befo), but could not able to resolve this error. Please help me to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't know if that is your problem but you need to change the add product method you got there: foreach (var product in products)
            {
                category.AddProduct(product); product.Category = category;
            }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to save the products before you save the category because you don't have a Cascade on the HasMany. 
And you need to change the add product methods to keep the relation

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    category.AddProduct(product); 
    product.Category = category;
}
```

Comment: Product is a child of Category. Product cannot be created without category.

Comment: @Nagesh Why is that? you can save it while it's null, anyway you need to changed the relation like I commented and added to my answer.

Comment: @Nagesh By the way, I think you need to understand what does inverse and cascase do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883900/what-does-inverse-and-cascade-means-in-nhibernate Is my question about it when I learned NH... GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Kindly provide me some links where I can download documentation regarding Hibernate.

Comment: Tutorials that a friend of mine published:  http://www.codecovered.net/2011/04/nhibernate-tutorial-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: Hi @gdoron, I'm struck with implementing composite key tables in nHibernate. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062068/nhibernate-error-message-invalid-index-3-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-c Kindly help me on this.